# Gitlab: use pipeline artifaces in other pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce, gitlab-pipelines

I'm migrating form Jenkins to Gitlab CI (self-hosted) and try to setup a workflow for all projects. One project is a Golang tool whose binary is required in other projects.
I've setup a working pipeline for the Golang project which builds a release with an attached binary for download. How can I reuse that binary in other project pipelines? Is there a way to download the binary with the REST API of Gitlab, or can I reuse the artifact of the release job in the other pipelines? I've searched the documentation of Gitlab and did not find an elegant solution for this yet :-/

Comment: Hello, if I understand , you can you trigger from your job to trigger another project. you can check documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html

Comment: I know this, but I don't want to build the binary for each job again, so I thought to reuse the release

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution now. It's possible to use curl to download the build artifact for reuse

```
curl -L --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <TOKEN>" "https://<HOSTNAME>/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/<ARTIFACT_PATH>?job=build" --output <BINARY_NAME>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).